# Jest is not generating the report table in my terminal

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

The issue I'm facing is the lack of report tables in my terminal once I run my `npm test`.
I know for a fact that the reports are being generated, since I can see the files in the `coverage` directory.

However, it's a bit annoying and despite my debugging, I can't seem to find out what the issue is.

Here is my jest.config.js:

```js
/*
 * For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property and type check, visit:
 * https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
 */

module.exports = {

  // Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
  clearMocks: true,

  // Indicates whether the coverage information should be collected while executing the test
  collectCoverage: true,

  // The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",

  // Indicates which provider should be used to instrument code for coverage
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  reporters: [
    "default",
    [
      "jest-junit",
      {
        outputDirectory: "./coverage",
        outputName: "unit_tests_coverage.xml",
      },
    ],
  ],

  // A list of reporter names that Jest uses when writing coverage reports
  coverageReporters: ["cobertura", "lcov"],

  // The maximum amount of workers used to run your tests. Can be specified as % or a number. E.g. maxWorkers: 10% will use 10% of your CPU amount + 1 as the maximum worker number. maxWorkers: 2 will use a maximum of 2 workers.
  maxWorkers: "50%",

  // A list of paths to directories that Jest should use to search for files in
  roots: ["test"],
  testEnvironment: "node",

  // Options that will be passed to the testEnvironment
  // testEnvironmentOptions: {},
  testRegex: ["/test/.*\\.(test|spec)?\\.(ts|tsx)$"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts?$": ["babel-jest"],
  },
}
```

At the end of every test execution, I get like a summary like this:

```
Test Suites: 9 passed, 9 total
Tests:       155 passed, 155 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.248 s
```

But no table showing line coverage, branch coverage... etc.

Is my jest.config.js incorrect or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you read https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coveragereporters-arraystring--string-options?

Comment: Just saw it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe, I managed to find out what the issue was.
Since I was using reporters, the default one (text) was overridden. So in order to see it again, I had to specify it manually (check [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coveragereporters-arraystring--string-options))

```js
...
coverageReporters: ["cobertura", "lcov", "text"],
...
```